# How to render a graphic d3.js with node.js using http

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, d3.js

I'm working with d3.js and node.js. I have a file .html with my d3.js code. In node.js I have the following code- The file .html contents the code of the graphic. I work with http in node.js,

```
fs.readFile('./grafico1.html' ,function(err,data ){
   if (err) return send404(res);
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
   res.end(data, 'utf-8');
   res.write(data);
   res.end();
```

});

Is this correct? Because I don't see the graphics in the web page?

Comment: You can check the problem with firebug or similar tools in browser. Maybe js files are not in the response.

Comment: Also try 3d mode in Firefox to see if the graphic is rendering outside the browser window.